# Adding List Data to Another List Based on Their Value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List:

```
    List<MenuItem> makanan = [
  MenuItem(
    gambarMenu: Image.asset('images/nasigoreng.jpeg'),
    namaMenu: 'Nasi Goreng',
    priceMenu: 'Rp. 15.000',
    qty: 0,
    note: 'Catatan',
  ),
  MenuItem(
    gambarMenu: Image.asset('images/mie goreng.jpeg'),
    namaMenu: 'Mie Goreng',
    priceMenu: 'Rp. 15.000',
    qty: 0,
    note: 'Catatan',
  ),
  MenuItem(
    gambarMenu: Image.asset('images/nasigoreng.jpeg'),
    namaMenu: 'Mie Kuah',
    priceMenu: 'Rp. 15.000',
    qty: 0,
    note: 'Catatan',
  ),
  MenuItem(
    gambarMenu: Image.asset('images/nasigoreng.jpeg'),
    namaMenu: 'Nasi Campur',
    priceMenu: 'Rp. 15.000',
    qty: 0,
    note: 'Catatan',
  ),
  MenuItem(
    gambarMenu: Image.asset('images/nasigoreng.jpeg'),
    namaMenu: 'Bakso Komplit',
    priceMenu: 'Rp. 15.000',
    qty: 0,
    note: 'Catatan',
  ),
];
```

also have Model that I want to make list from my previous list like this:

```
class TableOrder {
  String namaMakanan;
  int qtyMakanan;
  String noteMakanan;

  TableOrder({this.namaMakanan, this.qtyMakanan, this.noteMakanan});
}
```

How can I get data from previous list into new list based on their qty value, if the qty is more than 0 that data will be added into new list.

Comment: why dont you use List.where?

Comment: hi @DelphiX, I am new to Dart/Flutter, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use List.where and List.map like this:

```dart
final List<TableOrder> newList = makanan
  .where((item) => item.qty > 0)
  .map((item) => TableOrder(namaMakanan: item.namaMenu, ...))
  .toList();
```

Comment: this works even better, because using another model for new list instead of filtering the current model, I can able to reset the makanan list to zero without affecting the new list.

Answer (score 0):

use the where method of list

```dart
List<MenuItem> newMakanan = makanan.where((item) => item.qty > 0).toList();
```

[docs here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html)

Comment: thank you DelphiX, this works. but I changed a little bit ```List<MenuItem> newMakanan = makanan.where((i) => i.qty > 0).toList();```